# Laravel Session Forget using key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I've tried to use session forget of laravel but unfortunately I cant manage to run it also I'm trying to use UNSET() still not working, attached below is Controller for receiving a new product via saving is using array and validating whenever that product is already saved it will no be saved anymore.

```
$product_details = array('product_id'  => $request->get('product_id'), 
                         'product_qty' => $request->get('product_qty'));

$products = $request->session()->get('product');

if ($request->session()->has('product')) {

    foreach ($products as $key => $value) 
    {
        if($value['product_id']==$request->get('product_id'))
        {
            $request->session()->forget('product',$request->get('product_id'));
        }
    }

    session()->push('product', $product_details);
}
else
{
    session()->push('product', $product_details);
}

return true;
```

Comment: Its perfectly working but its not deleting the required product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question, this code should work and a bit of optimizing. You don't need to forget old product and add a new product, that waste of time, just add a flag `$product_exists` to define is exists or not then add/not add.

```
$product_details = array('product_id'  => $request->get('product_id'), 
                         'product_qty' => $request->get('product_qty'));
$product_exists = false;
if ($request->session()->has('product')) 
{
    $products = $request->session()->get('product');
    foreach ($products as $key => $value) 
    {
        if($value['product_id']==$request->get('product_id'))
        {
            $product_exists = true;
        }
    }
    if(!$product_exists){
        session()->push('product', $product_details);
    }
} else {
    session()->push('product', $product_details);
}
return true;
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I did my own version by using .$key

```
   $product_details = array('product_id'  => $request->get('product_id'), 
                             'product_qty' => $request->get('product_qty'));

    $products = $request->session()->get('product');

    if ($request->session()->has('product')) {

        foreach ($products as $key => $value) 
        {
            if($value['product_id']==$request->get('product_id'))
            {
                $request->session()->forget('product.'.$key);
            }
        }

        session()->push('product', $product_details);
    }
    else
    {
        session()->push('product', $product_details);
    }

    return true;
}
```